# How can I open a specific Tab of a Tabsheet with an Button in CUBA Platform?

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I created a Dashboard with a menubutton fragment. When I click on a button a new Screen is opening. And now I want to open a specific tab of this screen. In default always the first tab of a screen opens up, but I need to specify. My code looks like this:

```
public void onBaldUeberfaelligBtnClick() {
  screenBuilders.screen(this)
            .withScreenClass(AufgabenuebersichtBrowse.class)
            .build()
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a method in your `AufgabenuebersichtBrowse` class that switches to the needed tab. And then invoke this method after creating the screen, something like this:

```java
public class AufgabenuebersichtBrowse extends ... {

    @Inject
    private TabSheet tabSheet;

    public void switchToMyTab() {
        tabSheet.setSelectedTab("tab2");
    }
```

```java
public void onBaldUeberfaelligBtnClick() {
    AufgabenuebersichtBrowse screen = screenBuilders.screen(this)
            .withScreenClass(AufgabenuebersichtBrowse.class)
            .build();
    screen.switchToMyTab();
    screen.show();
}
```

See also the docs on opening screens: https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/opening_screens.html#screen_parameters

Comment: Thank you! Cuba cannot resolve this method. What do I have to do now?

Comment: @melli Of course you have to add the method to the browse screen controller. Updated my answer.